# Conditional Formatting multiple rules

Tags: excel-2007

I need cells to turn yellow greater than 20 days and red greater than 30 days from implementation date.I can get it to do one or the other but not both.

Comment: How can yo do one or other, but not both together?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the "between" condition for the 20 and "greater than" for 30

[image]

[image]

this worked for me as expected